# How to use 9.0.1 Firebase methods with VueJS 3

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vuejs3

I'm fairly new to Vue and this is the second tutorial I'm following, which integrates firebase backend with Vue. But the tutorial is using Vue 2 and also an older version of firebase, so I thought I could try to do it with Vue 3 and the new Firebase version.

The resources on the firebase 9.0.1 seems to be fairly limited with regards to implementation with Vue at least. This is what I found from the firebase documentation regarding the `signInAnonymously`

```
import { getAuth, signInAnonymously } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
signInAnonymously(auth)
  .then(() => {
    // Signed in..
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
  });
```

From what I understand, firebase 9.0.1 is an import only what you use style? so If I want to use the `getAuth` and `signInAnonymously` methods from the firebase/auth, I would do

```
import { getAuth, signInAnonymously } from 'firebase/auth';
```

But I am a bit confused as to how to use the methods in my .Vue file
so what I did in my firebase.js file was

```
export const auth = getAuth();
export {signInAnonymously};
```

then in my `Login.vue` file, i did

```
import { auth, signInAnonymously } from '../firebase'

export default {
    data() {
        return { auth }
    },
    methods: {
        signInAnonymously
    }
}
```

and I have a button that when clicked triggers the `signInAnonymously`, which is written like so

```
<button class="button" @click="signInAnonymously(auth)">Sign In</button>
```

What I have written seems to work, but I find it a bit convoluted/confusing and want to know

1. am I doing this correctly or is there a shorter/neater way to write the code?
2. what happens if I want to modify the `signInAnonymously` method as shown in the firebase documentation, i.e. adding those `signInAnonymously(auth).then(() => {})`, because if i were to add the arguments for the `signInAnonymously` in my export default like below, it doesn't recognize it as the exported method from my `firebase.js` file?

```
export default {
 ...,
 methods: {
   signInAnonymously(auth) {
     ...
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try creating a custom method and using `signInAnonymously()` within that as shown below:

```js
import { auth } from '../firebase'
import { signInAnonymously } from 'firebase/auth'
// can be imported directly in Login.vue ^^

export default {
  methods: {
    anonymousLogin() {
      // Directly pass 'auth' in this method
      signInAnonymously(auth)
        .then(() => {
          // Signed in..
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          const errorCode = error.code;
          const errorMessage = error.message;
          // ...
        });
    },
  },
};
```

Then use this custom method in `@click` event:

```html
<button class="button" type="button" @click="anonymousLogin">Sign In</button>
```